# Permissões Cakephp 3 - Autenticação

Tags: login, cakephp-3, permissões, auth

Boa tarde,

Alguém que já precisou de usar as restrições para o usuário via banco de forma editável que possa ajudar.

A principio segui o tutorial inicial criando as tabelas users e roles, porém o cliente pediu que possa editar as permissões de acesso da role por exemplo:

Roles | Permissions
ADMIN -> all;
EDITOR -> controller => POST, action ADD
EDITOR -> controller => POST, action EDIT
CLIENTE -> deny

Dessa forma criei a tabela permissions e roles_permissions e assim tentei passar no isAuthorized para permitir ou negar porém sem sucesso. Caso tenham um plugin que usem ou uma ideia melhor agradeço desde já.

```
 public function isAuthorized($user)
 {

    $this->rolePermissionsTable = TableRegistry::get('RolePermissions');

    $rolePermissions = $this->rolePermissionsTable->find()->where(['role_id' => $user['role_id'] ])->all();
   //var_dump($rolePermissions); die;

    $this->rolePermissionsTable = TableRegistry::get('RolePermissions');

    $this->permissionsTable = TableRegistry::get("permissions");
    // Admin pode acessar todas as actions
    foreach ($rolePermissions as $authorized) {
        $permissions = $this->permissionsTable->find()->where(['id', $authorized['permission_id'] ] )->all();


        if ($user['role_id']== $authorized['role_id']) {
            $this->addPermission($permissions);
            $this->Auth->allow('*');
            return true;
        }
        if($user['role_id'] != $authorized['role_id']){
            return false;
        }
    }
   // Bloqueia acesso por padrão
     return false;
 }


 public function addPermission($permissions){
    foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        $this->Auth->allow(['controller' => $permission['controller'], 'action' => $permission['action'] ]);
    }
 }
```

public function removePermission($permissions){
        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            $this->Auth->deny(['controller' => $permission['controller'], 'action' => $permission['action'] ]);
        }
     }

Answer (score 1):

Eu criei um plugin que controla o acesso de aplicativos no CakePHP 3, implementando ACL com gerenciador web. Inicialmente ele vem com 4 grupos, sendo super (o manda chuva), admin (pode tudo mas somente nas tabelas administrativas, que são groups, users e permissions), manager, que pode tudo mas somente nas tabelas de negócios (customers no app de exemplo) e user que não pode nada, somente efetuar login.

Você concede e remove permissões via web, em formulários, podendo conceder permissão para actions de controllers ou remover.

Também vem com layout usando o Bootstrap.

Veja um demo online aqui:
http://ribafs.org/demo

O demo só permite select. Instale localmente apra uma melhor experiência.

Download
https://github.com/ribafs/cake-control-br

Qualquer dúvida me diga.

Comment: Ficou show, segui este mesmo conceito com um mapeamento um pouco diferente e fiz uma criação dos menus dinamicamente através das permissões a Role que o usuário participa.